# Why I don't get the Access Token?

Tags: php, html, authentication, azure-active-directory, access-token

I'm try to do login script, where I want to login with the Microsoft OAuth2.0 and Azure Active Directory (or Mirosoft entra ID). The Authentification works and I get the Autorizecode, but the access token is not sent back to my OAuth2.0 provider from the success.php side. I've tried so many things like debugging, new code..., but nothing works. By the way, the authorization code is given on the success.php in the path above. Of course, all the data is changed for security reasons.

index.php

```
<?php

//TODO: Azure Synchronisation 

session_start();

     //* Überprüfen, ob der Benutzer authentifiziert ist
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/success.php');  //! Der Benutzer ist bereits authentifiziert
    exit();
}
else
{
header('Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/a502008d-5bd7-4ad1-b8e0-668da72219a8/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsuccess.php&response_mode=query&scope=openid+email+offline_access+profile+User.Read&state=12345&code_challenge=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code_challenge_method=S256');  //! Der Benutzer ist bereits authentifiziert
exit();
}
     
//* Überprüfen, ob der Benutzer bereits mit einem Office-Dienst verbunden ist
if (isset($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'])) 
{
sleep(1);
header('Location: http://localhost/success.php'); //! Der Benutzer ist bereits angemeldet
exit();
}



require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Assets/Configs/server.php'); //*Einbinden von server.php
$windowsUser = isset($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] : null; //*Variable für Authentifizierung
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; //* Datei autoload.php einbinden


use \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider; //* Composer (PHP-Bibliothek)

if($windowsUser) 
{
    
    $clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //* Anwendungs-ID (Client)
    $clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //* Geheime Clientschlüssel
    $tenantId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; //* Verzeichnis-ID (Mandant)
 
    //* Konfigurationsinformationen für OAuth2-Provider
    $provider = new GenericProvider([
        'clientId'                => $clientId,
        'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
        'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost/success.php', //* UmleitungsURI
        'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsuccess.php&response_mode=query&scope=openid+email+offline_access+profile+User.Read&state=12345&code_challenge=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code_challenge_method=S256",
        'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
        'scopes'                  => ['openid', 'email', 'offline_access', 'profile', 'User.Read'], //* Berechtigungen 
        'codeChallengeMethod'     => 'S256',
    ]);


    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $authorization_code = $_GET['code']; // Autorisierungscode aus GET-Parametern auslesen

        try {
            // Autorisierungscode verwenden, um Zugriffstoken zu erhalten
            $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                'code' => $authorization_code,
            ]);

            // JSON-Antwort in ein assoziatives Array umwandeln
            $response = json_decode($accessToken->getBody(), true);
            

            // Zugriffstoken speichern
            $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken->getToken();
            $_SESSION['id_token'] = $accessToken->getValues()['id_token'];

            $accessTokenValue = $accessToken->getToken();
            $_SESSION['accesstoken'] = $accessTokenValue;

            // Weiterleitung zur Erfolgsseite
            header('Location: http://localhost/success.php');
            exit();
        } catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
            
            echo "Fehler beim Abrufen des Zugriffstokens: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        // Benutzer muss sich einloggen und wird dann zu Azure AD weitergeleitet
        $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl(); // Autorisierungs-URL abrufen
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl); // Weiterleitung zur Autorisierungs-URL
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Success.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">

<?php
session_start();


$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$Erfolg ='Sie haben sich erfolgreich angemeldet';
?>

    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css.css">
        <title>
            Erfolg
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="Überschrift">
                <h1>ITH Bolting Technology - Login</h1>
                <?php
                    echo "Benutzer: ";
                    echo($username);
                ?>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h3>
                <?php
                    echo($Erfolg);
                    
    // Überprüfen, ob die Anzahl der Benutzer in der Session vorhanden ist
    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $authorization_code = $_GET['code'];
        echo "Autorisierungscode: " . $authorization_code;
    } else {
        echo "Autorisierungscode nicht gefunden.";
    }
    
    
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_count'])) {
        echo "<p>Anzahl der Benutzer aus Azure AD: " . $_SESSION['user_count'] . "</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Es wurden keine Benutzer abgerufen.</p>";
    }


    if(isset($_SESSION['accessToken']))
    {
        echo "Access Token: " . $_SESSION['accesstoken']; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Es wurde kein Accesstoken gefunden";
    }

                ?>
            </h3>       
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I successfully retrieved the **access token** from Azure Active Directory using the **PHP** code below.*

**Code :**

***index.php :***

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Microsoft OAuth Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Microsoft</h1>
    <a href="auth.php">Login with Microsoft</a>
</body>
</html>
```

***callback.php :***

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$clientId = '<client_ID>';
$clientSecret = '<client_secret>';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback.php';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $client = new Client([
        'verify' => false,
    ]);

    $tokenParams = [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id'     => $clientId,
            'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
            'code'          => $code,
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirectUri,
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $tokenResponse = $client->post($tokenUrl, $tokenParams);

        if ($tokenResponse->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $tokenData = json_decode($tokenResponse->getBody(), true);
            $accessToken = $tokenData['access_token'];

            echo "Access Token: $accessToken";
        } else {
            echo 'Error exchanging authorization code for access token: Unexpected response';
            http_response_code(500);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error exchanging authorization code for access token: ' . $e->getMessage();
        http_response_code(500);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Authorization code not found.';
    http_response_code(400);
}
?>
```

***auth.php :***

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
$clientId = '<client_ID>';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback.php';

$scope = urlencode('openid profile offline_access');
$authorizationUrl = "$authUrl?client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=$redirectUri&response_type=code&scope=$scope";
header("Location: $authorizationUrl");
exit;
?>
```

I added the following **URL** to the Azure app **Authentication** in **Web**:

```
http://localhost:8000/callback.php
```

[image]

I granted **openid**, **profile**, and **offline_access** to the app's **API permissions**, as shown below:

[image]

**Output :**

The PHP code ran successfully as shown below:

```php
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxxx>php -S localhost:8000
[Tue Feb 20 14:35:05 2024] PHP 8.3.0 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
```

[image]

Below is the output that appeared in the browser. I clicked on **Login with Microsoft** as shown below:

[image]

After being redirected to the login page, I clicked on my Azure account to log in as shown below:

[image]

*I successfully retrieved the **access token** as shown below.*

[image]

**VS code Terminal Output :**

```php
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxxx>php -S localhost:8000
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:19 2024] PHP 8.3.0 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:22 2024] [::1]:53800 Accepted
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:22 2024] [::1]:53800 [200]: GET /
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:22 2024] [::1]:53800 Closing
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:22 2024] [::1]:53801 Accepted
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:24 2024] [::1]:53802 Accepted
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:24 2024] [::1]:53801 [302]: GET /auth.php
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:24 2024] [::1]:53801 Closing
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:36 2024] [::1]:53802 [200]: GET /callback.php?code=0.ARoAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&session_state=34dd503axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:36 2024] [::1]:53802 Closing
[Tue Feb 20 14:30:36 2024] [::1]:53814 Accepted
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but do you know what was wrong in my Code, that I didn't get the Access Token?

Comment: @Patrick Based on your code, it seems like the issue might be related to how you're handling the retrieval and storage of the access token in your success.php file. Ensure that session_start() is called at the beginning of success.php, and double-check how you're storing and accessing the access token in the session variables.